# Highmaps + google sheets + javascript integration broken?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, highmaps

Is the integration between highmaps and google sheets not working?

It seems to have broken on a map I've been working on and in the process of debugging I can't seem to find one that is working. For example heading to this page: https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/data-class-two-ranges (or on the jsfiddle linked from that page)

it simply shows "Loading data from Google Spreadsheets"

Answer (score 0):

It's not working. There is an open ticket on the github here.

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8202